# Transfer system to another HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 installed on 320 GB HDD that is about to fail. I've bought new, 1 TB HDD and I want to migrate my system to it. The question is can I make (and how) an image of my current configuration - users, user's files, settings, apps installed, etc., get it to a USB/DVD and use it to install on my new HDD?! The idea is after the install all the configurations will be there?! Will it be a problem that the two drives are different in size?!

Comment: Clonezilla is made for exactly this.

Comment: As @OrganicMarble said, Clonezilla. I wrote a small answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259940/how-to-move-all-my-configuration-to-a-new-installation/1259944#1259944). This is pretty straightforward.